# MongoDB Java driver 3.1 conver find to array

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

In the older mongo drivers we could convert a `DBCursor` to array.
How can I accomplish it using mongo `Java` driver 3.1?

I have looked into mongo java driver api and found only this way:

```
MongoHandler.getCollection().find().sort(docSort).limit(ConstMongo.LIMIT_PLAYERS)
                .forEach(new Block<Document>() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(final Document document) {
                        arrResult.add(document.toJson());
                    }
                });
```

Is there a better and more clean way to do so?
And if not, why did they change the way we can access array of documents?

Answer (score 1):

In the Mongo 3.2 Java driver there is an `into` method that you can use to iterate over your results and put them into a collection

**Example**

```
List arrResult...
collection.find().into(arrResults);
```

See Java Doc http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.2/com/mongodb/client/MongoIterable.html#into-A-